# how to load sfb model from url in sceneform?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I m not able to load `.sfb` model from `URI.parse("url")` in sceneform.
My code is

```
 ModelRenderable.builder()
          .setSource(this, Uri.parse(string))
          //.setSource(this,R.raw.andy)
          .build()
         .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)

     /*     .thenAcceptBoth(futureTexture, (renderable, texture) -> {
              andyRenderable = renderable;

              andyRenderable.getMaterial().setTexture("None", texture);

          })*/
          .exceptionally(
                  throwable -> {
                      Toast toast =
                              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                      toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                      toast.show();
                      return null;
                  });
```

I know there is something wrong with sceneform in gradle. I used to load from Url back then. But I lost the setting or code..

Answer (score 0):

@rikesh shrestha

Here you cannot use URL directly in Uri.pare() as setSource(Context context, Uri uri) where Uri is the only path of a file only. So, you cannot use the URL directly. For more information [refere](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ModelRenderable.Builder#setSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri))

For that, you can do one thing. Download .sfb model file from URL and store it on some path. Then use this file path as Uri which helps you to achieve your goal.

I hope that you will resolve your issue.

Comment: i m able to load .sfb model from url after downloading it and passing through Uri.parse(). But the problem is when i converted .obj to .sfb inside raw folder and take to server to load from url , i was able to load it but when i converted throught the method in below link-> https://github.com/gdamoreira/google-ar-asset-converter . i couldn't load throught that url.

Comment: @rikeshshrestha   Have you compared both file which you have generated using **AndroidStudio Sceneform Tool** or **ArAssetConverter** Tool which you use? Or share both files

Comment: the difference is inside the pipeline data in model from assets folder and server file is the path location .is C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\input\\andy.obj. and sampledata/andy.obj ... i have changed the path of server location by changing it using url location .. but still not working for me

Comment: @rikeshshrestha Your are again doing a mistake here. The file from a server you have to get it (download) and store it in device local storage where you want to store. Then give this path in Uri.parse() method for loading model in AR Plane. Do not pass link directly to Uri.parse() method to load in ARPlane....

Comment: @rikeshshrestha If you want to load your moder directly without saving it into local storage ther use **gTLF model** to load in ARPlane. For [more information visit] (https://proandroiddev.com/fetching-models-at-runtime-with-sceneform-and-arcore-fde1a3bad060)

Comment: Appreciate for your help . But i have solved it @Hemal Patel.. the mistake was i didnot covert the model in script using Converter properly.

Comment: I am trying to solve the initial problem described above, I wonder how did you do it?Download sfb then render locally from device? https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/367

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the file that is downloaded from server it's better to use .glb files, as using .sfb files with Sceneform requires including information about them in gradle. Just download file from server and use it's path as the source. That worked for me.